# c:\inetput\mailroot is missing on recently installed computer with Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

`c:\inetpub`  is there, but not the subdirectory:  `mailroot\`

I recently installed a new HP server computer with Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation pre-installed.

Should `\mailroot\` automatically be installed, or is this a manual step?

It is needed for sending and receiving email to/from the web apps that I'm 
hosting on the server; web apps written in Visual Basic 2010, etc.

Comment: [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) may be a more appropriate choice for this type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my own Windows Server 2008 R2 server and I have no mailroot directory there either.  I would assume that this is not an automatically installed component.

Perhaps [How to: Install and Configure SMTP Virtual Servers in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b83ac7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will be of some help.

Comment: I added the SMTP feature to my Windows Server 2008, and that added the \Inetpub\mailroot.
But now the problem is how to add \Inetpub\mailroot\mailbox\ directories.